# How to add Gmail Go-to actions if we have multiple sender addresses

Tags: email, gmail, google-schemas

I wast just reading Gmail go-to actions (view actions) and following https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google to get the approval.

The [registration form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1) asks for

> From what email address are these emails sent? *
>   Please enter the full email address (e.g. noreply@mycompany.com)

Could it be possible to send emails with go-to actions if i have multiple sender emails of a single domain?

Ex: reply@sub1.x.com, sales@sub2.x.com

Another if i have y.com having SPF record to x.com (authorizing x.com to send emails), will the emails sent from y.com show the go-to actions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to send emails with go-to actions if you have multiple sender emails of a single domain.

Simply input the emails you plan on sending go-to actions from in the "*From what email address are these emails sent?*" field.

If the domains are different from each other, you will have to provide a sample email for both domains, as both domains will have to meet their [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#registration_guidelines).

To my understanding, the authenticated domain (SPF/DKIM) needs to match the "from:" email's domain. So, I guess in your scenario, to make it work, would be if y.com had a SPF record of x.com and additionally a DKIM record of y.com to show actions.

Comment: Actually they can be emails of users and can't be planned at this stage.
Let say my company (x.com) have sales@x.com, support@x.com email addresses.
but my customers can sign up for a customer1.x.com, now customer can also have their email addresses like support@customer1.x.com so emails sent from support@customer1.x.com, support@customer2.x.com ...support@customern.x.com should show gmail go to actions. How can I acheive that?

Comment: In the submission form, state that you'd like your domain "yourcompany.com" to be whitelisted.

Comment: Actually there is no such option in form. Can we state that in "Describe the email to which you plan to add schema. What is its purpose? " section

Comment: In the "From what email address are these emails sent?" field, input your domain.

Comment: Are you sure we can do that? I am afraid because they have asked for full email address. Not sure that would be right if we put domain instead of email address.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. However, if you're inputting domain like gmail.com (personal email) or amazonses.com (email client) it will not work. Please refer to their guidelines for more info https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#registration_guidelines